# как сделать динамический meter

Tags: javascript, php, html

Здравствуйте я новичок в данной теме, тем не менее мне хотелось бы узнать  возможно ли сделать  Meter который  обновляется сам по себе. У меня есть переменная  с числом и это число изменяется со временем мне нужно отображать это на  шкале в реальном времени, возможно ли осуществить это каким нибудь способом?

Comment: Надо слушатель навесить на число, которое меняется, и выполнять метод, в который передаётся значение этого числа.

Comment: `javascript`, событие `on-change`, далее `call-back функция`, ну а в функции уже все на ваше устмотрение и фантазию.

Comment: будет ли работать так?         
   <meter  id=met1 value=:=h_pros: max="10" low="3" high="6" min="0" optimum="8" onechange=myfunction(this.value)">lvl</meter> <br>
                       <p id="demo"></p> <br>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("met1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "znachenie: " + x;
}
</script>

Comment: Дайте лучше код с окружением. Будет понятнее.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы менялось значение value однако я не знаю как это сделать в meter  я пытался через Set interval  и переход по id к meter с указанием нового значения      <meter id="tprog" max="60" min="0" value=:=t_pros:>       setInterval (function () {  $. Get ("tpros. Html", function (result) { Var k =result. Trim() ; $('#tprog'). Value:=:t_pros:;}) ;}, 500);  в hpros. Html   стоит  out  '"t_pros"' и сам :="t_pros" :  так оно отслеживает изменение но только при перезагрузки страницы. Может можно как то запихнуть в div и обновлять только его каждые 0.5 сёк?